# How to make custom header image responsive

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I am working on a site and the theme is a responsive theme but the header background is not resizing on mobile and tablets
below is a link to the site
http://unitednews.sr/category/magazine/

each category has a unique header ,
this is what I have in css for category magazine

```
.category-3 #header-wrap { background: url( http://unitednews.sr/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Header_Unitedmagazine.jpg); }
```

how do I make them responsive ?

Answer (score 0):

You can put `background-repeat:no-repeat` and `background-size:cover` in the `.category-3 #header-wrap {}`.

Example:

```
.category-3 #header-wrap { 
    background: url( http://unitednews.sr/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Header_Unitedmagazine.jpg); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: background-size:cover does not seem to do the job

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the header background image from header itself to achieve results.

If you see HTML schema of theme it looks like this and it is already responsive.

```
<div id="header-wrap" class="clr"> <!--YOUR HEADER BACKGROUND LINE SPACE -->
            <header id="header" class="site-header clr container" role="banner">YOUR HEADER IMAGE SPACE</header>
</div>
```

Put your header background in #header-wrap and header/banner in #header. 
It should work.

**Modified**

Your header file should like this.

```
<div id="header-wrap" class="clr">
            <header id="header" class="site-header clr container" role="banner">                
    <img src="http://unitednews.sr/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/YOUR-CROPED-BANNER.jpg"><!--This isyour middle Area/banner of header, as explained above ->       </header><!-- #header -->
        </div>
```

Add your css style accordingly, you might have to remove the margins and padding around #header

This will be your banner which goes in #header
[image]

This will be your header-wrap which you repeat across

[image]

Comment: Where should i put that code ? functions.php Or header.php ?

Comment: You might able to do this without using any fucntion, just using styles and HTML You already have two containers Parent (header-wrap) and child(header). All you need to do is crop your current header image and split it into two. Take banner part(middle) separate from background lines. and using css assign background to parent and add image in child (header) container. You might need to read little bit about how to create a child theme http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: i already created a child theme and only have a css file in the theme. I should also have a header.php in my child theme folder ?

Comment: Ok i have just made a copy of header.php and placed it in the child theme folder , so now i have a .css file and a header.php file.        in the header.php file there is a line that says    `<div id="header-wrap" class="clr">
   <header id="header" class="site-header clr container" role="banner">`

Comment: If i do this the header image shows up accros the whole site , but i only want the header image to show up on a certain category .